# Getting error while writing dataframe to Ceph Storage

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, kubernetes, ceph

In my organisation I'm currently exploring how we can use Ceph to replace HDFS to run out AI/ML workloads. As part of this initiative we setup a Ceph Cluster and imported it into Kubernetes using Rook.

During my testing with Ceph I was able to access Ceph Storage using S3CMD CLI and also able to read data from Ceph using Spark on Kubernetes. However, I'm getting an error while writing data back to Ceph Storage.

Below is my code and error which I'm getting while writing data back. Hoping someone can help with this.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("prateek-pyspark-ceph") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.driver.master", "k8s://https://xxx:6443") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.namespace", "jupyter") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.container.image", "spark-executor-3.0.1") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy" ,"Always") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets" ,"gcr") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName", "spark") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.executor.serviceAccountName", "spark") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile", "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile", "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "xxxx") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "xxxx") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "{}:{}".format("http://xxxx", "8080")) \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.multiobjectdelete.enable", "false") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload","true") \
        .config("spark.eventLog.dir", "s3a://bucket/spark-event-log/") \
        .config("spark.executor.instances", "1") \
        .config("spark.executor.cores", "3") \
        .config("spark.executor.memory", "55g") \
        .config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "false") \
        .getOrCreate()

# Read Source Datasets 

musical_data= spark.read.json("s3a://bucket/input-data/Musical_Instruments_data.json")
musical_metadata= spark.read.json("s3a://bucket/input-data/Musical_Instruments_metadata.json")

# Register dataframes as temp tables 

musical_metadata.registerTempTable("musical_metadata")
musical_data.registerTempTable("musical_data")

# Top products based on unique user reviews

top_rated = spark.sql("""
select musical_data.asin as product_id, 
        count(distinct musical_data.reviewerID) as unique_reviewer_id_count, 
        musical_metadata.price as product_price
from musical_data left outer join musical_metadata
on musical_data.asin == musical_metadata.asin
group by product_id, product_price
order by unique_reviewer_id_count desc
limit 10
""")

# Display top 10 products

top_rated.show(truncate=False)

# Save output as csv

top_rated.write.format("csv") \
        .option("header","true") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .save("s3a://bucket/output-data/")

# Stop Spark Context to release resources 

spark.stop()
```

Error while writing Dataframe.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o740.save.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSBadRequestException: PUT 0-byte object  on output-data/_temporary/0/: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: null (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequest; Request ID: tx0000000000000000002b3-00604055fa-1ea62-sg; S3 Extended Request ID: 1ea62-sg-sg; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: 1ea62-sg-sg:InvalidRequest: null (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequest; Request ID: tx0000000000000000002b3-00604055fa-1ea62-sg; S3 Extended Request ID: 1ea62-sg-sg; Proxy: null)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$3(Invoker.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createEmptyObject(S3AFileSystem.java:2786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createFakeDirectory(S3AFileSystem.java:2761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerMkdirs(S3AFileSystem.java:2088)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.mkdirs(S3AFileSystem.java:2021)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:2275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:354)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:288)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: null (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequest; Request ID: tx0000000000000000002b3-00604055fa-1ea62-sg; S3 Extended Request ID: 1ea62-sg-sg; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: 1ea62-sg-sg
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1828)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1412)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1374)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5212)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5158)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:398)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:6113)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1817)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1777)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.putObjectDirect(S3AFileSystem.java:1545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.lambda$createEmptyObject$13(S3AFileSystem.java:2788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:109)
    ... 44 more
```

Versions -

Spark 3.0.1
Hadoop 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Finally the job worked in both Client and Cluster mode

**Cluster Mode via Spark Submit**

```
./spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://xxxx:6443 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name prateek-ceph-pyspark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=jupyter \
--conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
--conf spark.executor.cores=3 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=55g \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark-executor-3.0.1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.executor.serviceAccountName=spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets=gcr \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=<ACCESS_KEY> \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=<SECRET_KEY> \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=http://xxxx:8080 \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled=false \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access=true \
--conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false \
s3a://ceph-bucket/scripts/Ceph_PySpark.py
```

**Client Mode in Jupyter Notebook -**

`Spark Config with AWS Credential Provider - org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider`

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("prateek-pyspark-ceph") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.driver.master", "k8s://https://xxxx:6443") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.namespace", "jupyter") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.container.image", "spark-executor-3.0.1") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy" ,"Always") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets" ,"gcr") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName", "spark") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.executor.serviceAccountName", "spark") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile", "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile", "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "xxxxx") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "xxxxx") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "{​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​:{​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​".format("http://xxxx", "8080")) \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true") \
        .config("spark.executor.instances", "2") \
        .config("spark.executor.cores", "6") \
        .config("spark.executor.memory", "55g") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

`Spark Config with AWS Credential Provider - com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider`

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("prateek-pyspark-ceph") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.driver.master", "k8s://https://xxxx:6443") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.namespace", "jupyter") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.container.image", "spark-executor-3.0.1") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy" ,"Always") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets" ,"gcr") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName", "spark") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.executor.serviceAccountName", "spark") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile", "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt") \
        .config("spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile", "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "{​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​:{​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​".format("http://xxxx", "8080")) \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true") \
        .config("spark.executor.instances", "2") \
        .config("spark.executor.cores", "6") \
        .config("spark.executor.memory", "55g") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

To solve the issue in Writing to Ceph in Client Mode, add all properties related to `fs.s3a.committer.staging.*` mentioned here - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html in your `core-site.xml` file in both Driver and Executor image

Comment: Hi @Prateek Dubey, I am also using Ceph Storage to write the computation result. Though I am not using any s3a connector.  With "spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "1", it fails while renaming the part files at last stage but with"spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2", it works fine. Is there any recommendation from Ceph on this to use algorithm version "2"?